# Learn weights of features

Tags: cluster-analysis, weka

I want to use WEKA for learning the weights of the features that i am using in order to create clusters of documents. From each document I extract some features, but each feature has a different importance in the clustering method. 
I have a data set for the training, where each document is "represented" by the distance similarity per feature from another document and class one if they belong to the same cluster or 0. 
How I am using WEKA in order to learn the weights with cross validation? 
Thank you,
Evi

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions, not "how do I use Weka". Use the Weka book for this, it should be available in any good computer science library.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it is not possible to add weights in ARFF file format. Instead **XRFF** file format must be used. Further weights can be added to each individual instance or an attribute.

Check out the following links for examples.

http://weka.wikispaces.com/XRFF#Additional%20features-Attribute%20weights

http://weka.wikispaces.com/Add+weights+to+dataset

http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/can-I-weight-an-attribute-in-the-arff-file-td22889.html